# Ho to extract a specific cell from access database and put it into a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Hi is there a way to extract a specific column and row from an access database and put it in a text box? what I'm trying to do is a shopping app where if you click on a product picture, it opens a form with the details in it. I want to display its name and price on the two text boxes i made. For each product in the database, I made a primary key which is the product ID. Is there a way where i can put their values in the textbox using their ID's?

Comment: Information on retrieving data from a database and display it can be found all over the web.  It is likely the easiest to possibly find relating to programming.  You clearly have made no effort on your own behalf so posting a question here is premature.  Do your research, write the code you think you need and then, if it doesn't work as expected, post a question here explaining exactly what you've done and how your results differ from your expectation.  We'll be happy to help then.  That's what this site is for.

Comment: Agree with jmc, this is basic Access functionality. Open bound form with bound textboxes that is filtered by the selected product ID. Any introductory tutorial will describe this process.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i know how to set an oledb connection, select from table and retrieve data from access to textboxes. What I'm trying to know is, for example, i have a  product, primary key is product id which is '1', its name is 'cake' and its price is '10'. Im trying to know if its possible to type a code that finds the productid then automatically puts the product name and price on the txtname and txtprice textboxes. I made an effort but i havent found yet. all is the same. it doesnt look for specific cell it looks for  i dont know maybe im searching the wrong keywords.

Comment: "maybe im searching the wrong keywords". Then maybe you need to put programming on hold for a little while and learn how to use a search engine.  Seriously, if you know how to write MOST of the code then write MOST of the code and ask about the part that you are SPECIFICALLY having a problem with.  If you're really having a problem with displaying data in a `TextBox` then there's something seriously wrong.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ok. I can't ask a question here without a code because it will look like i want the solution to fall right on my lap. i got that. its not like that man. I'm just having a hard time searching keywords in english. I'll be back with a code if theres any more problem. i was hoping for a link to a syntax or something like that. I didnt know how this site works its my 3rd day visiting here. Ill be back with a code.

Comment: All you need is to add a filter to your query, which you do with a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

On the OnClick property of the button/product picture, open the Detail form with a filter on it.  Like this:

```
Private Sub MyButton_OnClick()
  DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMyFormName", , , "ProductID=" & txtProductID.Text
End Sub
```

Then, bind MyFormName to the table of data, and bind the textboxes/labels to the appropriate fields in that table.  Keep in mind that if you use textboxes, anyone can change the values unless you disable the fields.

The above statement will simply open the form and display **only** the record(s) where ProductID is equal to the value you're searching for.  Make sure ProductID is an Primary Key field or you're going to return multiple records.